# which radio type i'm using

Tags: wifi, frequency, capability

How can I ,from the network information like frequency ,network speed ,security type "capabilities" and signal level in dBm to determin which standard i'm using.
Well i can get easely  two categories from the frequency 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz ,but still not giving me an accurate result 
802.11a (5GHz) /802.11b (2,4GHz) /802.11g (2,4GHz) /802.11n(5GHz  et 2,4GHz)
In another hand i saw in some sites that we can determin the standard from the network speed
802.11a (54Mb/s) /802.11b (11Mb/s) /802.11g (54Mb/s) /802.11n(300Mb/s)
 but those numbers are theoritical ,and interference problems can accure to change them.
I'm confused ,can someone give me an idea to resolve my problem.
Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

The access point announces the available rates it supports in the beacon frame. Maybe [this article](http://ccie-or-null.net/2011/06/22/802-11-beacon-frames/) can help you get started.